# How to parse the response of a Solr Analysis request in java/solrj?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

i have a java program to make requests in a solr server. I created a query that triggers the analysis service of solr :

```
HttpSolrClient server = new 
HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/docs");
            SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
            query.setRequestHandler("/analysis/field");
            query.set("analysis.fieldtype", "text_en");
            query.set("analysis.fieldvalue", "TESTS");
            query.set("wt", "json");
```

The response i get back is something like:

```
{responseHeader={status=0,QTime=2},analysis={field_types={text_en={index={org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer=[{text=TESTS,raw_bytes=[54 45 53 54 53],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1]}],org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.StopFilter=[{text=TESTS,raw_bytes=[54 45 53 54 53],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1, 1]}],org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.LowerCaseFilter=[{text=tests,raw_bytes=[74 65 73 74 73],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1, 1, 1]}],org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishPossessiveFilter=[{text=tests,raw_bytes=[74 65 73 74 73],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1, 1, 1, 1]}],org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.SetKeywordMarkerFilter=[{text=tests,raw_bytes=[74 65 73 74 73],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.KeywordAttribute#keyword=false}],org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.PorterStemFilter=[{text=test,raw_bytes=[74 65 73 74],start=0,end=5,org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength=1,type=<ALPHANUM>,position=1,positionHistory=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.KeywordAttribute#keyword=false}]}}},field_names={}}}
```

Which is not a valid json. I want to parse it and get the texts i.e. "tests", "test".

I can only retrieve the analysis part by :

```
response.getResponse().get("analysis");
```

which is a class org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap Object.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should have a look at the FieldAnalysisRequest. I found an example here http://useof.org/java-open-source/org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.FieldAnalysisRequest/2 Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I finally used another solution. With an http request in:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/docs/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue={custom}&analysis.fieldtype={custom}
```

I get back the result in a valid json format.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's a sin of Solr, as you mentioned it's not valid json, but it's rather string representation of what is called in Solr a [NamedList](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/util/NamedList.html) (SimpleOrderedMap is a subclass of NamedList)

> A simple container class for modeling an ordered list of name/value
>   pairs. Unlike Maps:
>
> - Names may be repeated
> - Order of elements is maintained
> - Elements may be accessed by numeric index
> - Names and Values can both be null
>
>   NamedList provides fast access by element number, but not by name.

Unfortunately, there are no built in support for transforming NamedList, so, you have to write custom Java code, that will extract needed properties out of NamedList

The other possibility is to use [FieldAnalysisRequest](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/FieldAnalysisRequest.html), which will return it [FieldAnalysisResponse](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/FieldAnalysisResponse.html), which have a methods like:

```
getFieldNameAnalysis(String fieldName)
```

which will give you `FieldAnalysisResponse.Analysis`

From two possible solutions, I will recommend the latter, since it will be much easier to grasp and maintain.

Comment: thank you, i tried it with fieldanalysisrequest but still i was getting the response in the same way. I finally found another solution which i have posted as an answer too.